# Encased For loops causing issues

Tags: java, loops

Trying to get my output to look like the following: `UserInputViaCommand: match1, match2`

But it is displaying:  `UserInputViaCommand: match1, UserInputViaCommand: match2`

I know this is due to the second for loop being inside the first one, but I am unsure about to to go about getting my desired output.

My program is run from the command line like so: `java program name1 name2 < names.txt`

I read the file and normalize names within it and then read the user input and do the same and if they match print them out.

```
try {
    InputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while ((nameFile = InputReader.readLine()) != null) {
        //Normalising the input to find matches
        nameFromFile = normalize(nameFile);
        //Looping through each argument
        for (int j = 0; j < ags.length; j++) {
            // Appending text to the string builder
            //Output.append(ags[j] + ":" + " ");
            //Normalising the input to find matches
            String result = normalize(ags[j]);
            if (nameFromFile.equalsIgnoreCase(result)) {
                Output.append(ags[j] + ":" + " " + nameFile + ", ");
                //Output.append(ags[j] + ":" + " ");
                //Output.append(nameFile + ", ");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Output);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting `for` loop. Why aren't you using a `while` loop? You've basically made that `for` into a `while`.

Comment: @crush I have made crazy amount of changes, i think it was a while loop at one stage. I will change it back and see if I can play with it. :) Changed to a while loop :)

Comment: Your example output doesn't seem to match your code. It seems the output should be more something like: `Name1: name1, name2: name2`. So either you changed something in the meantime or the code you left out is the important part.

Comment: Is `UserInputViaCommand` a name through command line (`name1, name2`) and `match1`, `match2` lines from `names.txt`?

Comment: @jkbkot Sorry it is when the first argument has multiple matches it displays: `name1: match1 name1: match2`

Comment: @PopoFibo Yes that is correct. The user input can match many names from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of doing it would be using a check for `ags[j] + ":"` already appearing in your buffer, given that user input through command line would be distinct

So your inner if condition would be something like:

```
if (nameFromFile.equalsIgnoreCase(result)) {
    if (!output.toString().contains(ags[j] + ":"))
        output.append(ags[j] + ":");
    output.append(" " + nameFile + ", ");

}
```

Another possibility can be loops' order can be reversed, you read through the user args first setting the `output.append(ags[j] + ":");` in the outer loop and then seeking to the start of the file to read through it for the second arg (I would use `RandomAccessFile` to easily seek to the start of the file):

Something like:

```
try {

            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(new File(
                    "C://users//XX//desktop//names.txt"),
                    "rw");

            for (int j = 0; j < args.length; j++) {
                output.append(args[j] + ":");
                while ((nameFile = raf.readLine()) != null) {

                    if (args[j].equalsIgnoreCase(nameFile)) {
                        output.append(" " + nameFile + ", ");

                    }

                }
                raf.seek(0);
            }
            System.out.println(output + "\r\n");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

One can contend the inefficiency of seeking to the start of the file but if it is not a bottleneck then is a feasible option.

Comment: Thank you so very much. :) The first example works charmingly :)